# Getting and Setting selected index JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I'm working on a i18n application in JAVA.
I'm using `JSpinner` with a `String[]` as model to allow user to select some option.
My problem is the text in `JSpinner` is changing by language.
so I wan't use index of selected option instead of its value.
How can I get (and set) selected index in a `JSpinner`?

Comment: You could always get the selected value from the spinner and use this to search the model for its index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the value of the JSpinner, than iterate through it's data (whatever List you set it to), and find the index of it. To set the index, just get the object at the index you want, and set the object to that. See examples below. You could also make your own SpinnerModel

Searching example:

```
public int getSelectedIndex(JSpinner spinner, List<?> values) {
    int index=0;
    for(Object o :values) {
        if(o.equals(spinner.getValue()))
            return index;
        index++;
    }
    return -1;
}
public void setSelectedIndex(JSpinner spinner, List<?> values, int index) {
    spinner.setValue(values.get(index));
}
```